# Outter container ( Images surrounding div element )

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, frontend

[image: Block images surrounding div]

I need to create a kind-of 'outter' container of images to surround a div which contains text. Please see the attached image for a rough idea of what i'm trying to achieve. I've tried using columns with bootstrap but I'm unable to create the image overlap effect (on the right-hand side).

```
<!-- Top Layer -->
<div class="col-md-12"><img src="image1.png"></div>

<!-- Left Layer -->
<div class="col-md-3"><img src="image2.png"></div>

<!-- Text (Middle) -->
<div class="col-md-6"><p>This is the text This is the text</p></div>

<!-- Right Layer -->
<div class="col-md-3"><img src="image3.png"></div>
```

But this obviously causes problem with the long image on the right-hand side.
Any ideas how to complete this with CSS?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What _“image overlap effect (on the right-hand side)”_ …?

Comment: The longer image on the right that stretches down past the height of the element in which it's contained.

Comment: Yeah, ok, in that regard it probably makes sense to start this with 3-6-3 columns as the outer structure ... First columns gets the three pictures on the left, second gets image on top and content underneath, and third gets the two images to the right. Then it won’t matter much any more, how high the images actually are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it as 3 columns, although you haven't described how you would like this to look on smaller screens as the columns will collapse in order. The below snippet is a **rough** example of what you could do.

```css
.padded {
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Left Column -->
<div class="center-block" style="width: 80%">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="padded" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="padded" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="padded" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text (Middle) -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <div class="text-center">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100" class="padded" />
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
          This is the text This is the text
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Right Column -->
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
      <div class="row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x200" class="padded" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="padded" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, from what i can get, you need to arrange the images kind-of as an inverted 'U'- shaped and place the text in the between of the two side images. The idea is to `float` the images `left` or `right` accordingly and then set the display of the text as `inline-block`.

The following code places 4 boxes in an arrangement as asked in the question, you can align them as you want using `margin-left` property.

**NOTE** This arrangement is only possible if the boxes/divs are wide enough, so make sure to adjust the widths of each div. Not necessarily as i have done you can change it as you wish, just make sure that the boxes are wide enough to fill in the page or the arrangement will not show up.

```css
#top{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 20%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: red;
}

#left{
 height: 50%;
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 background-color: blue;
}

#text{
 height: 50%;
 width: 50%;
 background-color: green;
 text-align: center;
 float: left;
}

#right{
 height: 50%;
 width: 25%;
 background-color: yellow;
 float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id='top'></div>
<div id='left'></div>
<div id='right'></div>
<div id="text"></div>
</body>
```

**EDIT** Don't know why stackOverflow is not able to show the result on running this code, but i suggest you copy it and run it manually, it will show something like the image attached.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```css
.left-container, .right-container {
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
}
.center-container {
  float: left;
}
.img-small {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.img-big {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.img-wide {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}
.text {
  width: 80px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class='left-container'>
    <div class='img-small'></div>
    <div class='img-small'></div>
    <div class='img-small'></div>
    <div class='img-small'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='center-container'>
    <div class='img-wide'></div>
    <div class='text'></div>
  </div>
  <div class='right-container'>
    <div class='img-small'></div>
    <div class='img-big'></div>
    <div class='img-small'></div>
    <div class='img-small'></div>
  </div>
</body>
```